# Asking about websites recommendations is allowed behaviour or breaks any rule?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

There is certain explicit functionality I'm trying to get and that used to be available at a given website. Offline now but maybe there is a replacement or another one that serves the same functionality. I would like to know if I'm allowed to ask in that specific way?

Comment: There is no way to ask this that would be considered on-topic. Questions about websites are off-topic and questions seeking product/service recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: You could try [webapps.se]

Comment: Recommendations in general are out of scope at Super User

Answer (score 1):

To quote the close reasons:

> Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers.

So, in a word - no, this won't be on topic.